# Remove special characters surrounded by white space

Tags: java, regex, web

How can i remove special characters having white space on side.

```
String webcontent = "This is my string. i got this string from blabla.com."
```

When i use this regex

```
webcontent.replaceAll("[-.:,+^]*", "");
```

it becomes like this

```
String webcontent = "This is my string i got this string from blablacom"
```

which is not good i want

```
"This is my string i got this string from blabla.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

You must test the presence of a white character or the end of the string with a lookahead `(?=...)` (followed by):

```
webcontent.replaceAll("[-.?:,+^\\s]+(?:(?=\\s)|$)", "");
```

The lookahead is only a test and doesn't consume characters.

If you want to do the same with all punctuation characters, you can use the unicode punctuation charcater class: `\p{Punct}`

```
webcontent.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}\\s+^]+(?:(?=\\s)|$)", "");
```

*(note that `+` and `^` are not punctuation characters.)*

Comment: If the dot is in the beginning like that `.This is my string. i got this string from blabla.com.`

Comment: Thank you @Casimir et Hippolyte and anubhava for your nice and clean help. It works for me. i want to know (just for knowledge) what if String contains "?" it self, then how can we remove this because ? is helping char in regex. I tried .replaceAll("[.|:,+?]+(?!\\w)", ""); but it does not work.

Comment: @user1642500 use escape `\\` character.

Comment: @user1642500 I have added it in my post. Just move it outside `[.|:,+?]` and use `[.|:,+]|\\?`

Comment: @user1642500: inside a character class `?` has no special meaning, thus you can put it without escaping it: `[-.:+?\\s]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead to avoid this:

```
webcontent = webcontent.replaceAll("[-.:?,+^]+(?!\\w)", "");
//=> This is my string i got this string from blabla.com
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava for your help. I added comment about removing ? character. How can we do that.

Comment: That just needs addition of `?` in character class. See edited answer.

Comment: It should work without `\\?` what is your input string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 // any one or more special characters followed by space or in the end
 // replace with single space

 webcontent.replaceAll("[-.:,+]+(\\s|$)", " ").trim();
```

---

--EDIT--

if the special character is in the beginning

```
 webcontent.replaceAll("^([-.:,+]+)|[-.:,+]+(\\s|$)", " ").trim();
```

input:

```
.This is my string. i got this string from blabla.com.
```

output:

```
This is my string i got this string from blabla.com
```

---

--EDIT--

I want to replace `?` also

```
webcontent.replaceAll("^([-.:,+]+|\\?+)|([-.:,+]+|\\?+)(\\s|$)", " ").trim();
```

input

```
..This is my string.. ?? i got this string from blabla.com..
```

output

```
This is my string  i got this string from blabla.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `[-.:?,+^](\s|$)` and remove the character for each match with basic string manipulation. It's a few more lines of code but much, much cleaner.

A pure java solutions where you loop over all special characters and check the next character is also quite simple.

As soon as there are lookaheads/lookbehinds involved, I usually fall back to a non-regex solution for clarity.

Comment: What about other special characters?

Comment: If the dot is in the beginning like that `.This is my string. i got this string from blabla.com.`

Comment: You have to define **what** you wan't to replace. *Special characters surrounded by whitespace* does not sufficiently describe what you want. The more exceptions you have the more complex your regex or replacement logic will be. If it works for `.`, you can make it work for everything.

Comment: OK No worries. I got it now. I think I have added it already it in my post.